# python, COM and multithreading issue

Tags: python, internet-explorer, com, automation

I'm trying to take a look at IE's DOM from a separate thread that dispatched IE, and for some properties I'm getting a "no such interface supported" error. I managed to reduce the problem to this script:

```python
import threading, time

import pythoncom
from win32com.client import Dispatch, gencache
gencache.EnsureModule('{3050F1C5-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}', 0, 4, 0) # MSHTML

def main():
    pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(0)
    ie = Dispatch('InternetExplorer.Application')
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate('http://www.Rhodia-ecommerce.com/')
    while ie.Busy:
        time.sleep(1)

    def printframes():
        pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(0)
        document = ie.Document
        frames = document.getElementsByTagName(u'frame')
        for frame in frames:
            obj = frame.contentWindow

    thr = threading.Thread(target=printframes)
    thr.start()
    thr.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thr = threading.Thread(target=main)
    thr.start()
    thr.join()
```

Everything is fine until the `frame.contentWindow`. Then bam:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python22\lib\threading.py", line 414, in __bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\python22\lib\threading.py", line 402, in run
    apply(self.__target, self.__args, self.__kwargs)
  File "testie.py", line 42, in printframes
    obj = frame.contentWindow
  File "C:\python22\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 455, in __getattr__
    return self._ApplyTypes_(*args)
  File "C:\python22\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 446, in _ApplyTypes_
    return self._get_good_object_(
com_error: (-2147467262, 'No such interface supported', None, None)
```

Any hint ?

Comment: Orthogonal to your question: update to Python2.7; try [selenium](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html)

Comment: Not an option right now; I'm in a commercial context and we do much more than what Selenium does. We're on the way to upgrade Python though :) We found a workaround by using apartment instead of free threading and marshalling stuff by hand but I'm still curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is to marshal stuff by hand. That's not a workaround it is what you are supposed to do here. You shouldn't have to use apartment threading though.

You initialised as multithreaded apartment - that tells COM that **it** can call **your interfaces** on any thread. It does **not** allow you to call other interfaces on any thread, or excuse you from marshalling interfaces provided by COM. That will only work "by accident" - E.g. if the object you are calling happens to be an in-process MTA object, it won't matter.

`CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`/`CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream` does the business.

The reason for this is that objects can provide their own proxies, which may or may not be free-threaded. (Or indeed provide custom marshalling). You have to marshal them to tell them they are moving between threads. If the proxy is free threaded, you may get the same pointer back.